# Is this a thread-safe RNG method?

Tags: c++, random, concurrency

Is it safe to call `A::generateID()` from multiple threads?

```
class A
{
public:
    std::string generateID()
    {
        unsigned long rndNumber = dist(gen);
    
        std::string result;
        result.resize(5);
    
        result[0] = LETTERS[(rndNumber >> (6*0)) & 0x3f];
        result[1] = LETTERS[(rndNumber >> (6*1)) & 0x3f];
        result[2] = LETTERS[(rndNumber >> (6*2)) & 0x3f];
        result[3] = LETTERS[(rndNumber >> (6*3)) & 0x3f];
        result[4] = LETTERS[(rndNumber >> (6*4)) & 0x3f];
    
        return result;
    }

private:
    unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::mt19937_64 gen = std::mt19937_64(seed); //Has the best performance compared to other RNG engines
    std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned long> dist = std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned long>(0, std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max());

    const std::string LETTERS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789&$";
};
```

Of course, the easiest way would be just putting everything in `generateID()` but I want to do as much work as possible in the object instatiation to make the function call as fast as possible and it must be thread-safe. The problem is, `dist(gen)` seems to change the internal state of the RNG engine but I can't find any information about the race conditions of `std::uniform_int_distribution::operator()`.

Comment: It's as save as `dist()` from a first glance assuming you create it before the threads.

Comment: AFAIK `std::mt19937_64` and `uniform_int_distribution` are not thread safe, so that would make `generateID` also not threadsafe.

Comment: Why not just give every thread their own RNG?

Comment: The general rule is that C++ library classes are not thread-safe unless specifically stated to be so.  If the same object is shared by multiple threads, you need locking if either one is going to modify the object or call non-const member functions of it.  Otherwise it's a data race and the behavior is undefined.  (However, you are assured that modifying one library object won't cause data races with *other* or hidden global state, unless specified otherwise.)

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Looks like I'll have to give every thread their own RNG.

Comment: You don't need `uniform_int_distribution` `std::mt19937_64` already is the way you are using it.  However it's not thread safe. If you use separate gens each takes 5k of stack/no heap.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not, `uniform_int_distribution` is not thread safe.

And it's actually much worse, because you're using one uniformly-distributed random value and generate 5 random values from it that are absolutely not uniformly-distributed. If you want 5 random values, request 5 values from your generator. You're not gaining anything with your anti-pattern.

Comment: Also, don't store the seed, you're wasting memory. And you're relying on order of operations to initialize your generator before the seed, which is an undefined behaviour. The more I read your code the lower I'm rating it.

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with generating lots of random bits at once and chopping them up? Shouldn't the distribution be of equal quality? The only change I would make is changing `unsigned long` to a fixed width integer type.

Comment: @Blindy Regarding *And you're relying on order of operations to initialize your generator before the seed, which is an undefined behaviour* It is not UB.  class members are constructed in the order they appear in the class.  What is, is brittle code and a bad pratice.

Comment: No, only the original number you're chopping off is guaranteed to follow the selected distribution. Any operation you're making on it with deterministic entropy (in this case, no entropy) doesn't follow the original distribution.

Comment: For a uniform distribution, aren't each bit independently uniformly distributed? Edit : At least for a power-of-two distribution range.

Comment: It's just converting the random number to a base64 string. The string will be uniformly distributed.